# Using OpenGraph with PHP (cUrl requests for actions)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I created an app for my website, set action (read) and object (article), and placed the objects code (META tags in the head) at the article page on my website.

Now, I want to know how to send a cUrl request whenever a user reads an article on my website, so it'll feature on his wall.

When I press the "get code" link near the action, that's what I get:

```
curl -F 'access_token=***' \
 -F 'article=http://example.com' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/yellowheart:read'
```

(There's an actual access token of course).

Now, how do I make it happen?

Daniel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the PHP SDK you would use the [api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) method.

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
...
$facebook->api('https://graph.facebook.com/me/yellowheart:read?  
                article=http://example.com'','POST');
```

You could also do a raw request

```
$myurl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/yellowheart:read? 
          article=http://example.com&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=post';

$result = file_get_contents($myurl);
```

Comment: Where do you set the access_token?

Comment: @Zorayr - I have edited to explicitly show the config variable in the api case and the parameter in the raw request

Answer (score 1):

```
$facebook->api('/me/'.FB_NAME_SPACE.':action','POST',
   array('facility'=>'http://www.mysite.com/object?id=1')
                             );
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Answer (score 0):

I followed [the tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/) "Recipe Box" and found out how to "make it happen" in there step by step. Hope that helps in some way.