# Facebook Open Graph - how to rewrite publish JS function to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using this scheme for publishing my action to the timeline:

```
    function postCook()
          {
              FB.api(
                '/me/app_url:action',
                'post',
                { object: 'url address' },
                function(response) {
                   if (!response || response.error) {
                      console.log(response);
                      alert('Error occured');
                   } else {
                      alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                   }
                });
          }
<input type="button" value="Cook" onclick="postCook()" />
```

How could I rewrite this JS function into PHP? I've tried something like this (what I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686422/using-opengraph-with-php-curl-requests-for-actions)):

```
$myurl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/url_app_name:action?object=url_address&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=post';
$result = file_get_contents($myurl);
```

But this returns me the error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(content of $myurl) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in...
```

How could I publish Open Graph action in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend checking out the [Facebook PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/). The documentation is pretty good (as far as Facebook goes) and it will abstract the messy file_get_contents() stuff.